# Gini coefficient calculation using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write some code to calculate the Gini index for a fake country. I've came up with the following:

```
GDP = (653200000000)
A = (0.49 * GDP) / 100 # Poorest 10%
B = (0.59 * GDP) / 100
C = (0.69 * GDP) / 100
D = (0.79 * GDP) / 100
E = (1.89 * GDP) / 100
F = (2.55 * GDP) / 100
G = (5.0 * GDP) / 100
H = (10.0 * GDP) / 100
I = (18.0 * GDP) / 100
J = (60.0 * GDP) / 100 # Richest 10%

# Divide into quintiles and total income within each quintile
Q1 = float(A + B) # lowest quintile
Q2 = float(C + D) # second quintile
Q3 = float(E + F) # third quintile
Q4 = float(G + H) # fourth quintile
Q5 = float(I + J) # fifth quintile

# Calculate the percent of total income in each quintile
T1 = float((100 * Q1) / GDP) / 100
T2 = float((100 * Q2) / GDP) / 100
T3 = float((100 * Q3) / GDP) / 100
T4 = float((100 * Q4) / GDP) / 100
T5 = float((100 * Q5) / GDP) / 100

TR = float(T1 + T2 + T3 + T4 + T5)

# Calculate the cumulative percentage of household income
H1 = float(T1)
H2 = float(T1+T2)
H3 = float(T1+T2+T3)
H4 = float(T1+T2+T3+T4)
H5 = float(T1+T2+T3+T4+T5)

# Magic! Using numpy to calculate area under Lorenz curve.
# Problem might be here?
import numpy as np 
from numpy import trapz

# The y values. Cumulative percentage of incomes
y = np.array([Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5])

# Compute the area using the composite trapezoidal rule.
area_lorenz = trapz(y, dx=5)

# Calculate the area below the perfect equality line.
area_perfect = (Q5 * H5) / 2

# Seems to work fine until here. 
# Manually calculated Gini using the values given for the areas above 
# turns out at .58 which seems reasonable?

Gini = area_perfect - area_lorenz

# Prints utter nonsense.
print Gini
```

The result of `Gini = area_perfect - area_lorenz` just makes no sense. I've took out the values given by the area variables and did the math by hand and it came out fairly ok, but when I try to get the program to do it, it gives me a completely ??? value (-1.7198...). What am I missing?

Comment: print the value of area_perfect and area_lorenz and debug it. Are they int or float?

Comment: Why do you have dx=5? I would think dx should be .2, so that the total distance in x is 1.0.

Comment: Actually anna, you're right! Thank you!
There were also a few other errors in the math that I managed to find (after taking a break, haha) and apparently that corrected it.

I still don't get how that'd affect the actual issue tho. Anyway, it is a non-issue now!

Comment: @Anna, @stardust, that's not right. Changing `dx` to 0.2 makes `Gini` equal to 175763056000.0. The real problem is in the definition of `area_perfect`. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

A first issue is not factoring for the equation for the Gini coefficient correctly:

> gini = (area between Lorenz curve and perfect equality) / (area under
> perfect equality)

The denominator in was not incldued in the calculations, and an incorrect equation for the area under the line of equality is also being used (see code for a method using [np.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) and [np.trapz](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)).

There is also the issue that the first point of the Lorenz curve is missing (it needs to start at 0, not the first quintile's share). Although the area under the Lorenz curve is small between 0 and the first quintile, its ratio to the area under the line of equality after that is extended is quite large.

The following provides an equivalent answer to the methods [given in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512260/calculating-gini-coefficient-in-python-numpy):

```py
import numpy as np
    
GDP = 653200000000 # this value isn't actually needed
    
# Decile percents of global GDP
gdp_decile_percents = [0.49, 0.59, 0.69, 0.79, 1.89, 2.55, 5.0, 10.0, 18.0, 60.0]
print('Percents sum to 100:', sum(gdp_decile_percents) == 100)
    
gdp_decile_shares = [i/100 for i in gdp_decile_percents]
    
# Convert to quintile shares of total GDP
gdp_quintile_shares = [(gdp_decile_shares[i] + gdp_decile_shares[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(gdp_decile_shares), 2)]
    
# Insert 0 for the first value in the Lorenz curve
gdp_quintile_shares.insert(0, 0)
    
# Cumulative sum of shares (Lorenz curve values)
shares_cumsum = np.cumsum(a=gdp_quintile_shares, axis=None)
    
# Perfect equality line
pe_line = np.linspace(start=0.0, stop=1.0, num=len(shares_cumsum))

area_under_lorenz = np.trapz(y=shares_cumsum, dx=1/len(shares_cumsum))
area_under_pe = np.trapz(y=pe_line, dx=1/len(shares_cumsum))
    
gini = (area_under_pe - area_under_lorenz) / area_under_pe
    
print('Gini coefficient:', gini)
```

The areas calculated with `np.trapz` give a coefficient of 0.67. The value calculated without the first point of the Lorenz curve and using trapz was 0.59. Our calculation of global inequality is now roughly equal to that provided by the methods in the question linked above (you do not need to add 0 to the lists/arrays in those methods). Note that using [scipy.integrate.simps](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) gives 0.69, meaning the methods in the other question coincide more with trapezoidal than Simpson integration.

Here's the plot, which includes `plt.fill_between` to color under the Lorenz curve:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(pe_line, shares_cumsum, label='lorenz_curve')
plt.plot(pe_line, pe_line, label='perfect_equality')
plt.fill_between(pe_line, shares_cumsum)
plt.title('Gini: {}'.format(gini), fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Cummulative Share of Global GDP', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Income Quintiles (Lowest to Highest)', fontsize=15)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: The resulting gini curve.]

Answer (score 1):

Stardust.

Your problem isn't with `numpy.trapz`; it is with 1) your definition of the *perfect equality* distribution, and 2) normalization of the Gini coefficient.

First, you had defined the perfect equality distribution as `Q5*H5/2`, which is half the product of the fifth quintile's income and the cumulative percentage (1.0). I'm not sure what this number is meant to represent.

Second, you have to normalize by the area under the *perfect equality* distribution; i.e.:

> gini = (area under perfect equality - area under lorenz)/(area under perfect equality)

You don't have to worry about this if you define the perfect equality curve to have an area of 1, but it's a good safeguard in case there's an error in your definition of the perfect equality curve.

To address both of these issues, I defined the perfect equality curve with `numpy.linspace`. The first advantage of this is that you can use the real distribution's properties to define it the same way. In other words, whether you use quartiles or quintiles or deciles, the perfect equality CDF (`y_pe`, below) will have the right shape. The second advantage is that computing its area is done with `numpy.trapz` as well, a bit of parallelism that makes the code easier to read and guards against erroneous calculations.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import trapz

GDP = (653200000000)
A = (0.49 * GDP) / 100 # Poorest 10%
B = (0.59 * GDP) / 100
C = (0.69 * GDP) / 100
D = (0.79 * GDP) / 100
E = (1.89 * GDP) / 100
F = (2.55 * GDP) / 100
G = (5.0 * GDP) / 100
H = (10.0 * GDP) / 100
I = (18.0 * GDP) / 100
J = (60.0 * GDP) / 100 # Richest 10%

# Divide into quintiles and total income within each quintile
Q1 = float(A + B) # lowest quintile
Q2 = float(C + D) # second quintile
Q3 = float(E + F) # third quintile
Q4 = float(G + H) # fourth quintile
Q5 = float(I + J) # fifth quintile

# Calculate the percent of total income in each quintile
T1 = float((100 * Q1) / GDP) / 100
T2 = float((100 * Q2) / GDP) / 100
T3 = float((100 * Q3) / GDP) / 100
T4 = float((100 * Q4) / GDP) / 100
T5 = float((100 * Q5) / GDP) / 100

TR = float(T1 + T2 + T3 + T4 + T5)

# Calculate the cumulative percentage of household income
H1 = float(T1)
H2 = float(T1+T2)
H3 = float(T1+T2+T3)
H4 = float(T1+T2+T3+T4)
H5 = float(T1+T2+T3+T4+T5)

# The y values. Cumulative percentage of incomes
y = np.array([H1,H2,H3,H4,H5])

# The perfect equality y values. Cumulative percentage of incomes.
y_pe = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,len(y))

# Compute the area using the composite trapezoidal rule.
area_lorenz = np.trapz(y, dx=5)

# Calculate the area below the perfect equality line.
area_perfect = np.trapz(y_pe, dx=5)

# Seems to work fine until here. 
# Manually calculated Gini using the values given for the areas above 
# turns out at .58 which seems reasonable?

Gini = (area_perfect - area_lorenz)/area_perfect

print Gini

plt.plot(y,label='lorenz')
plt.plot(y_pe,label='perfect_equality')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```