# How can I get Gini Coefficient in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gini

I would like in sklearn package, Find the gini coefficients for each feature on a class of paths
such as in iris data. like Iris-virginica  Petal length gini：0.4   ，Petal width gini：0.4.

Comment: Can you post the data on which you want to find the gini ?

Comment: `from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
`u can use this code download data

Comment: Don't confuse Gini coefficient and Gini impurity. This [article](https://www.learndatasci.com/glossary/gini-impurity/) shows a very comprehensive python implementation of the latter.

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the gini coefficient with Python+numpy like this:

```
from typing import List
from itertools import combinations

import numpy as np

def gini(x: List[float]) -> float:
    x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)
    n = len(x)
    diffs = sum(abs(i - j) for i, j in combinations(x, r=2))
    return diffs / (2 * n**2 * x.mean())
```

Comment: This is one of the best Gini implementations in Python that I've seen :-D.  I love it because there are a lot of alternative formulas out there, but if you look around this is the most agreed upon and consistent Gini formula you'll see in literature.  The issue is that it's hard to implement this formula, and yet here it is in just 4 lines of code.  Well done!!  A+

Comment: I might have spoke too soon.  I was comparing this to some other work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512260/calculating-gini-coefficient-in-python-numpy) and I wonder if you're over estimating n here.  We want the mean absolute different, and your n is > the number of mean absolute differences that you calculate (from what I can see).

Comment: Hower, the original equation contains permutations, not the combination used in the code!