# Python: Weighted coefficient of variation

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, standard-deviation, weighted

How can I calculate the **weighted [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation)** (CV) over a NumPy array in Python? It's okay to use any popular third-party Python package for this purpose.

I can calculate the CV using [`scipy.stats.variation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.variation.html#scipy.stats.variation), but it's not weighted.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import variation

arr = np.arange(-5, 5)
weights = np.arange(9, -1, -1)  # Same size as arr
cv = abs(variation(arr))  # Isn't weighted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [`statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.html) class in the [`statsmodels`](https://pypi.org/project/statsmodels/) package for calculating [weighted statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_statistics).

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import DescrStatsW

arr = np.arange(-5, 5)
weights = np.arange(9, -1, -1)  # Same size as arr

dsw = DescrStatsW(arr, weights)
cv = dsw.std / abs(dsw.mean)  # weighted std / abs of weighted mean

print(cv)
1.6583123951777001
```

For a related statistic, i.e. the weighted gini, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49571213/).

---

Credit: This answer is motivated by one on calculating the [weighted standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36464881/).